# Where Inventory_stock_% table get updated in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory, out-of-stock

The problem I'm facing is that 
The table `Inventory_stock_13` used for the 2nd website is updated incorrectly.
When set source status to `Out of stock`, column `is_salable` is still 1 and `quantity` is updated to 0 instead. 
Expected result must be `is_salable` to 0 and `quantity` unchanged.

I can only see the default stock item get saved but cannot find where the code update table 'Inventory_stock_13'? 
Hope you guys have a hint for me. Thank you.

I'm working on magento 2.4.3 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out myself. Patch these two will get the other inventory stocks updated like the logic of the default one.

```
@package magento/module-inventory-indexer
--- Indexer/SelectBuilder.php

+++ Indexer/SelectBuilder.php   (date 1631043163343)
@@ -79,11 +79,12 @@
             []
         );

+        $this->getIsStockItemSalableCondition->stockStatusColumn = '`status`';
         $select->from(
             ['source_item' => $sourceItemTable],
             [
                 SourceItemInterface::SKU,
-                IndexStructure::QUANTITY => 'SUM(' . $quantityExpression . ')',
+                IndexStructure::QUANTITY => 'SUM(`' . SourceItemInterface::QUANTITY . '`)',
                 IndexStructure::IS_SALABLE => $this->getIsStockItemSalableCondition->execute($select),
             ]
         )


@package magento/module-inventory-sales
--- Model/ResourceModel/IsStockItemSalableCondition/IsStockItemSalableConditionChain.php
+++ Model/ResourceModel/IsStockItemSalableCondition/IsStockItemSalableConditionChain.php    (date 1631043236344)
@@ -66,6 +66,6 @@
         }

         $isSalableString = '(' . implode(') OR (', $conditionStrings) . ')';
-        return (string)$this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->getCheckSql($isSalableString, 1, 0);
+        return (string)$this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->getCheckSql($isSalableString, isset($this->stockStatusColumn) ? $this->stockStatusColumn : 1, 0);
     }
 }
```